# Table filling width with 2 columns each as multi-row

Tags: latex, tabular

I am trying to setup a table with 2 columns. It should fill the whole width of a A4 page.

Each column should contain a `\multirow` (different number of rows for each column).

The left column should be aligned on the left, the right column should be aligned on the right.

I am struggling with the details of the space filled between the columns. So far I've tried with the usual `tabular` package, but also with `longtable`, but I see all sorts of indentation problems. It seems like these packages don't honor the `geometry` details of the page.

See here:

```
% \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{\tabcolsep}} l r}
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{0.5\linewidth}>{\raggedleft}p{0.5\linewidth}}
  \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{l}xx \\ zz \\ \end{tabular}} & 
  \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{r}xx \\ zz \\ \end{tabular}} \\
\end{tabular}
% \end{longtable}
```

I would like to have 2 columns:

- one on the far left, aligned on the left
- the other on the far right, aligned on the right
- no frames, or lines, just the text/words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need frames and the columns have different number of rows anyway, why not place two `minipage`s besides each other instead of using a table?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\raggedright
xx

zz
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\raggedleft
xx

zz
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing this and it works quite well. I just used stuff like `\begin{flushright}` instead of `\raggedright`.